# How to compute density of states for very large numbers of atoms?

Tags: condensed-matter, eigenvalue, density-of-states

I have a code to compute density of states of an Hamiltonian $H$. I'd like to compute it for a very large number of atoms (Currently I'm performing simulations with 1000 atoms, with polarization the matrix is 2000x2000, the goal would be to achieve simulations over 30 000 atoms, thus a matrix of 60 000 x 60 000) and I can't ignore any interactions. The network of atoms is 2D hexagonal. Things to know:

- I don't want to compute all the eigenvalues, only those around the GAP are of relevant interest.
- $H$ isn't Hermitian it is just a matrix without any particularity
- The DOS doesn't need to be very precise, if I can have a convergent algorithm that improves the global result for each iteration it's okay

What I already do:

- Use eigen3 and C++
- OpenMP for parallelization

I've heard of the *Wang and Landau algorithm* but it doesn't fit my need as my system isn't characterized by a cost function. So, do you know some papers or works that could help me?